# Get the element with text and its parent doesn't have text

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="a">
  <div>Histogram
    <em>Median</em>
  </div>
  <div>
    <em>Median</em>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, how to get the second node contains 'Median' using xpath?

`//div[@class="a"]//*[text()="Median"]` will give two nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following-sibling

```
//div[@class="a"]/div[em[text()="Median"]]/following-sibling::div/em
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(/div[@class="a"]//*[text()="Median"])[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below `xpath`.

```
(//div[@class='a']//em[text()='Median'])[last()]
```